# Using BeautifulSoup in CGI without installing

Tags: python, module, ftp, beautifulsoup, cgi

I am trying to build  a simple scraper in Python, which will run on a Webserver via CGI. Basically it will return a value determined by a parameter passed to it in a URL. I need BeautifulSoup to do the processing of HTML pages on the webserver. However, I'm using HelioHost, which doesn't give me shell access or pip etc. I can only use FTP. One the BS website, it says you can directly extract it and use it without installing.

So I got the tarball on my Win7 machine, used 7-zip to remove bz2 compression, and then tar compression, which gave me a `bs4` folder and a `setup.py` file. I transferred the complete `bs4` folder to my `cgi-bin` directory where the python script is located via ftp. My script code is :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()


import urllib
import urllib2
from bs4 import *

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print "<html><head><title>CGI Demo</title></head>"
print "<h1>Hello World</h1>"
print "</html>"
```

But it is giving me an error:

```
 /home/poiasd/public_html/cgi-bin/lel.py
    6 import urllib
    7 import urllib2
    8 from bs4 import *
    9 
   10 print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
bs4 undefined
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (__init__.py, line 29) 
      args = ('invalid syntax', ('/home/poiasd/public_html/cgi-bin/bs4/__init__.py', 29, 6, 'from .builder import builder_registry\n')) 
      filename = '/home/poiasd/public_html/cgi-bin/bs4/__init__.py' 
      lineno = 29 
      msg = 'invalid syntax' 
      offset = 6 
      print_file_and_line = None 
      text = 'from .builder import builder_registry\n'
```

How can I use the `bs4` module via CGI? How can I install but not-install it? Can I convert the BeautifulSoup I have on my PC to a nice little `BeautifulSoup4.py` which will contain all the code?

Comment: What version of Python 2 is this? It looks like you are using Python 2.4 or earlier; BeautifulSoup 4 requires Python 2.7 or up, but *may* work on 2.6 as well.

Comment: [BeautifulSoup 3](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html) works on older Python 2 versions; it'll have some bugs and some newer features are missing, but perhaps it'll suffice for your needs.

Comment: Martijn Pieters thanks a ton, I was on 2.4, any the BS3 single python file worked like a charm :)

Comment: Glad that worked for you; I expanded that into an answer (rather than you adding a 'solved' section). Feel free to mark it as accepted if it was helpful to you. :-)

Comment: Please use http://pythonanywhere.com/ instead. I've tried both, and they're uncomparable.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a version of Python that doesn't yet support [PEP 328 Relative Imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/); e.g. Python 2.4 or older. BeautifulSoup 4 requires Python 2.7 or newer.

Presumably you cannot upgrade to a newer Python version. In that case you can try using [BeautifulSoup 3](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html); it'll have a few bugs and you'll be missing some features, but at least you can get past the syntax error.

However, I note that HelioHost does [list Python 2.7 as supported](http://www.heliohost.org/home/features/languages/python).

Comment: Even I saw python 2.7 in the 500 Error page, but the cgi debug page shows 2.4

Comment: @user3857675: you could try using `#!/usr/bin/python2.7` perhaps, but you may want to ask Helios support. I don't see anything helpful on their pages, their Snakecharmer samples are down and the forum pages time out.