# Using Wikipedia and Requests in CGI without installing

Tags: python, python-requests, cgi

I have a simple mashup CGI program written in Python (2.6) that, among other sources, should grab the summary of Wikipedia articles to present to the user along with results from several other sources (as it is what mashups are supposed to do). Unfortunately I have no access to the console on the remote server and therefore I cannot install any modules using pip, easy_install, etc. Following the suggestion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27341351/using-beautifulsoup-in-cgi-without-installing), I have been able to use BeautifulSoup4. However, I had no success when attempting to use the same strategy (unpacking the source directory and uploading it the cgi-bin directory in the remote server) with the [wikipedia](https://github.com/goldsmith/Wikipedia) and [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) modules.

Here is the test script I am using:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

import urllib
import urllib2

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#import requests
#import wikipedia

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print "<html><head><title>CGI Demo</title></head>"
print "<h1>Hello World</h1>"
print "</html>"
```

If I enable the lines that import the requests and wikipedia modules, I get the dreadful "500 Internal Server Error", otherwise the script runs OK.

So, my question is, is it possible to use the wikipedia and requests modules (in fact, wikipedia depends upon requests) without installing them in the usual ways?

Thanks in advance for any hints or suggestions.

Comment: Without console access you probably won't be able to install `requests`. But you can fetch data from `wikipedia.org` using just the standard library.

Comment: I still question why it works with BeautifulSoup but not requests. Sure, it can be done without requests, but by no means easily.

Comment: I have no idea why BeautifulSoup is installed into the Python on your system. It's not a part of the standard library. You'll probably need to ask your system administrator.

Comment: It is not pre-installed. I installed it myself, without console access, by uploading the source directory to my cgi-bin folder (see the link in my question). If this trick worked for BeautifulSoup, I don't understand why it cannot work for other modules too (at least if they are written in pure Python, without C extensions).

Comment: Well, the problem of course is that requests has many dependencies, which in turn also depends upon other modules, and this in practice makes it impossible to use sucessfully these modules without installation. Too bad!

Comment: Yes, `requests` has many third-party dependencies, most notably the Python `cryptography` module which depends on native C support.